# Not able to use namespace clojure.data.zip.xml in Clojure

Tags: xml, clojure, namespaces

I'm following [this article](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/parsing_xml_with_zippers.html) for XML parsing. It has an example code which doesn't work for me when I play out in the REPL:

```
(require '[clojure.data.zip.xml :as zip-xml])
```

It throws me the following error: `FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/data/zip/xml__init.class or clojure/data/zip/xml.clj on classpath`

I'm using leiningen for the project and have the following dependecies defined in the project:

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
[org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]
```

Any ideas on what's the problem ?

Comment: Have you restarted your repl before adding the dependencies? Because I have just tried to reproduce you error and it didn't work. If you have, I 'd recommend to run a "lein clean" from the project folder and starting a new nrepl afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several problems ranging from project layout to needing to restart nrepl. To help with this here is a working project to test against:

```
git clone git@github.com:thearthur/zip-xml-example.git
```

project.clj:

```
(defproject zip-example "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"                                                                                                                                  
  :description "FIXME: write description"                                                                                                                                 
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"                                                                                                                                         
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"                                                                                                                                
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}                                                                                                             
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]                                                                                                                            
                 [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]])
```

core.clj:

```
(ns zip-example.core                                                                                                                                                      
  (:require [clojure.data.zip.xml :as zip-xml]                                                                                                                            
            [clojure.zip :as zip]                                                     
            [clojure.xml :as xml]                                                                                                                                         
            [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]))                                                                                                                            

(def xml                                                                                                                                                                  
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\" ?>                                                                                                                       
 <!-- <!DOCTYPE nzb PUBLIC \"-//newzBin//DTD NZB 1.1//EN \"  \"http://www.newzbin.com/DTD/nzb/nzb-1.1.dtd \"> -->                                                           
<nzb xmlns=\"http://www.newzbin.com/DTD/2003/nzb\">                                                                                                                       
 <head>                                                                                                                                                                   
   <meta type=\"title \">Your File!</meta>                                                                                                                                
   <meta type=\"tag \">Example</meta>                                                                                                                                     
 </head>                                                                                                                                                                  
 <file poster=\"Joe Bloggs &lt;bloggs@nowhere.example&gt;\" date=\"1071674882\" subject=\"Here's your file!  abc-mr2a.r01 (1/2)\">                                        
 <groups>                                                                                                                                                                 
 <group>alt.binaries.newzbin</group>                                                                                                                                      
 <group>alt.binaries.mojo</group>                                                                                                                                         
 </groups>                                                                                                                                                                
 <segments>                                                                                                                                                                
 <segment bytes= \"102394\" number= \"1\">123456789abcdef@news.newzbin.com</segment>                                                                                      
 <segment bytes= \"4501\" number= \"2\">987654321fedbca@news.newzbin.com</segment>                                                                                        
 </segments>                                                                                                                                                              
 </file>                                                                                                                                                                  
 </nzb>")                                                                                                                                                                 

(spit "test.xml" xml)                                                                                                                                                     
(def parsed-xml (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse "test.xml")))                                                                                                                     
(pprint (zip-xml/xml-> parsed-xml :head :meta))
```

Comment: To save other peoples' hair-pulling. Start your location predicates inside the top element, e.g. `:head :meta` rather than `:nzb :head :meta`.